# Using Selenium To Capture A Value In Webpage Automation

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

I am working a python selenium script to pull shipping times between zipcodes from the UPS website. "http://ltl.upsfreight.com/shipping/transittimes/transittimes.aspx"

My code works until I attempt to capture the shiptime. How do I pick up the value? Below is the html from chrome holding the value "1" I want to capture.

```
<span id="app_ctl00_ctl01_lblServiceDays" style="font-weight:bold;">1</span>
```

And the code itself:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('http://ltl.upsfreight.com/shipping/transittimes/transittimes.aspx')
driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl00_OriginZipCodeSelector_OriginZipCodeSelector_txtZip").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl00_OriginZipCodeSelector_OriginZipCodeSelector_txtZip").send_keys("07042")
driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl00_DestinationZipCodeSelector_DestinationZipCodeSelector_txtZip").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl00_DestinationZipCodeSelector_DestinationZipCodeSelector_txtZip").send_keys("07059")
driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl00_btnSubmit").click()
shiptime = driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl01_lblServiceDays")
print (shiptime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `.get_attribute('value')` or `.text` at the end of `shiptime = driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl01_lblServiceDays")`

Depends the type of the field you are trying to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. Add some delay in your code like ImplicitlyWait of 3/5 seconds as below for the webpage HTML DOM to load. Your code will work fine.

The equivalent java code for ImplicitlyWait is:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I added it before the print - but it did not return

    shiptime = driver.find_element_by_id("app_ctl00_ctl01_lblServiceDays")
    print (shiptime)